# Repeating a function n amount of times in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, function, 2d

```
class Game(wall: List[(Int, Int)], bounty: List[(Int,Int, Int=> Int)], var playerX: Int, var playerY: Int)
 private var field: Array[Array[Boolean]] = Array.ofDim[Boolean](10, 10)
private var bounties: Array[Array[Int=>Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int=>Int](10, 10)

def al() {
    playerX = playerX - 1
    checkBounty();
    if(field(playerX)(playerY) == true) {
      playerX = playerX - 0
      getPlayerPos();
    }
    }
```

This is the code to move the player one place to the left.

```
I wanna delegate the function above al() into the function al(n: Int) and it should be repeated n amount of times.
can anyone please help me with that?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
def repeat(n: Int)(f: () => Unit) {
  0 until n foreach { _ => 
    f()
  }
}

repeat(n)(al)
```